# ComboBox Unreadable in Multithreaded

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms

I'm trying to build a small application that connects to a couple databases to move data from one to the other, manipulating and verifying data is it moves. I had everything working, but wanted to add the majority of the work to a second thread so that the initial window is still functional.

I have most of it working fine so far, except for one pesky bit. I allow the user to choose the database from a list of databases on a MSSQL Server. Without the threading, the program can read the text of the combo box without issue. As soon as I add in threading, it can't read the text of the combo box. It doesn't have issues reading the text boxes that contain the servername/username/password, just with this one combo box. The code below is in a class that handles all my database functions. The combobox is on the main form (frmMain) that is launched when you run the application. frmMain is the default form for the application.

Without threading I was doing this.

```
Me._sqlDB = New sqlDatabase
Me._sqlDB.DBServer = frmMain.txtServer.Text
Me._sqlDB.DBUsername = frmMain.txtUser.Text
Me._sqlDB.DBPassword = frmMain.txtPassword.Text
Me._sqlDB.DBDatabase = frmMain.cboSQLDatabase.Text
```

When I added the thread, it couldn't read from the combo box (along with a host of other issues due to non-threadsafe calls). I did some research and added in some delegates and invokes. This solved the rest of the issues I was running into, but the combobox was still unreadable.

I created a function with a delegate to read the combobox, hoping that it was a thread related issue, but still no luck. The database connection setup code is in the database class I mentioned above and the GetDatabaseName function is in the main form (frmMain).

```
'Database Connection Setup
Me._sqlDB = New sqlDatabase
Me._sqlDB.DBServer = frmMain.txtServer.Text
Me._sqlDB.DBUsername = frmMain.txtUser.Text
Me._sqlDB.DBPassword = frmMain.txtPassword.Text
Me._sqlDB.DBDatabase = frmMain.GetDatabaseName

'GetDatabaseName Function for Connection String Setup
Delegate Function GetDatabaseNameDel() As String

Public Function GetDatabaseName() As String
    Dim DBName As String = ""
    If Me.cboSQLDatabase.InvokeRequired Then
        DBName = Me.Invoke(New GetDatabaseNameDel(AddressOf GetDatabaseName))
    Else
        DBName = Me.cboSQLDatabase.Text
    End If
    Return DBName
End Function
```

I have tried several of the combobox properties, including SelectedItem, SelectedText, and Text. None of them have any value when the GetDatabaseName function is called. In fact, when run in debug mode and pausing the code execution, Visual Studio shows that the combobox has nothing in it (Count = 0, Items collection is empty).

The combobox is populated using a SqlDataReader that reads the list of database names from the server.

I also tried changing the setup to use a BackgroundWorker, but I get the same results.

Any thoughts on why the combobox is appearing as empty when running as a separate thread?

---

With a little more research, I found a possible solution, but it seems really janky. If I change the call to the function to use this:

```
Me._sqlDB.DBDatabase = CType(My.Application.OpenForms.Item("frmMain"), frmMain).GetDatabaseName
```

It works, but this seems like a very odd workaround for the issue. Is there a better way to refer to the control on the active form?

Comment: Have you tried `return Me.Invoke(New GetDatabaseNameDel(AddressOf GetDatabaseName))` or otherwise storing the return value and then return it later. It might just LOOK empty because you aren't doing anything with the value upon invoking

Comment: I've never seen it hit that branch of the If statement. The InvokeRequired has never been true in all the times I have run it.

Comment: Have you tried cboSQLDatabase.InvokeRequired instead?

Comment: Jens: Do you mean taking off the Me. from in front of that line?

Comment: No, replace Me. with cboSQLDatabase. (aka check the actual control if it needs to be revoked instead of the parent form. It might work, it might not, I can't say for sure :-))

Comment: I'm not checking the parent form...check the code again. "If Me.cboSQLDatabase.InvokeRequired Then"

Comment: What is `frmMain` in your code?  Is it a variable or is it a class?  I'm guessing that it's a class and, if so, that's your issue.  In that case, you're using the default instance and the default instance is thread-specific.  If you test `InvokeRequired` on the default instance of a form then it will always be False because the default instance you access was always created on the current thread.

Comment: Adding info on frmMain to the question. Assuming that the default instance thing is the problem, what is the solution?